# how can i correct Imagick code in php?

Tags: php

```
$image=new Imagick();
$image->readImage("image.jpg");
$image->setImageFileName("imagecopy.jpg");
$image->writeImage();
```

i am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
> 'unable to open image `image.jpg': No such file or directory @
> error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2514' in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick\1.php:41
>
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick\1.php(41):
> Imagick->readimage('image.jpg') #1 {main} thrown in

any one know how can i correct it.

Comment: "unable to open image" probably means you're not specifying the right path to the image

Comment: Or that you do not have Imageck installed.

Comment: or you dont have the correct file permissions set.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug with ImageMagick. It uses the Apache core dir as reference. You can work around this by using `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` to construct an absolute path.

For example, to use the script's directory, do the following:

```
$im = new imagick (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'a.jpg');
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try This one :

```
$image=new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "your image folder path"."image.jpg");
$image->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "your image folder path"."image.jpg");
$image->setImageFileName("imagecopy.jpg");
$image->writeImage();
```